# Invoke-WebRequest or wget unable to download PS1 files from url

Tags: powershell

I'm running a .ps1 script which basically downloads all files that it finds from a remote url. The url has directory browsing enabled in IIS and I can see all the files in a browser.

All files download correctly but when it tries download any .ps1 files it fails saying: 404 - File or directory not found. The file is definitely there.

```
wget $url/test.ps1 -outfile $destPath\test.ps1
```

and

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url/$basename -OutFile $destPath\$basename
```

both fail with a 404 error. I have verified that $url, $basename and $destPath return the correct values. I can rename the same file to test.exe and it downloads it fine. Any other file I try to download using the methods above works (txt, exe files) but not PS1 files. I also noticed if I have other files with ext like .xyz it too errors on it and isn't downloaded. Maybe some MIME type setting I need to configure in IIS?

Or is there some kind of filter happening with those commands that don't let you download powershell script files? Either on the local machine or the remote machine? Does it check IE settings and something needs to be turned on or off?

I even tried this script which also downloads files from website but same issue:

http://vcloud-lab.com/entries/powershell/microsoft-powershell-download-a-whole-folder-of-files-subfolders-from-the-web-directory

Answer (score 0):

Ahh I got it. Had to add this inside the  of web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension="*" mimeType="text/plain" /><!-- or application/octet-stream -->
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```